# Writing $n$ as the sum of $m$ positive integers (without order)

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $p(n,m)$ denote the number of ways of writing the integer $n$ as a sum of $m$ positive integers, regardless of any ordering.
>
> 1. Prove that $p(n,m)=0$ if $m>n$
> 2. Prove that $p(n,1)=1$
> 3. Prove that $p(n,m)=p(n-1,m-1)+p(n-m,m)$ if $n\geq m>1$

1. and 2. are trivial. I'm stuck with 3.

A natural thought would be to consider $2$ cases:

- there is $1$ among the integers in the decomposition (hence $p(n-1,m-1)$)
- there is no $1$ in the decomposition. But why should that account for  $p(n-m,m)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_m$ is a decomposition that has no 1, then $a_1-1, a_2-1, a_3-1, \ldots, a_m-1$ is a decomposition of $n-m$.

Comment: Nice trick, thanks.